# Julia SimpleHypergraphs - Hypernetx Error

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I tried to compute a small example with the library [SimpleHypergraphs](https://github.com/pszufe/SimpleHypergraphs.jl). I followed the install instructions however, I have this error :

```
ERROR: "HyperNetX is not installed in Python used by this Julia. Install HyperNetX and reload SimpleHypergraphs.jl"
```

Here's my code:

```
using PyCall
using Conda
Conda.runconda(`install matplotlib --yes`)
Conda.runconda(`install networkx --yes`)
run(`$(PyCall.python) -m pip install hypernetx`)

using SimpleHypergraphs

h = Hypergraph{Float64}(5,4)

h[1:3,1] .= 1.5
h[3,4] = 2.5
h[2,3] = 3.5
h[4,3:4] .= 4.5
h[5,4] = 5.5
h[5,2] = 6.5

draw(h, HyperNetX; width=5, height=5)
```

I don't understand why this error occurs since hypernetx is well installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `pandas` has been added to the dependencies of `hypernetx` and now it will not load unless pandas is available.

Restart your Julia session and run

```
using Conda
Conda.runconda(`install pandas --yes`)
```

Now it will work as expected:

```
draw(h, HyperNetX; width=5, height=5)
```

[image]

Thanks for posting that out! - I will add it to the README of SimpleHypergraphs.
Finally, note that SimpleHypergraphs uses the Python only for the last step - plotting. All processing/computations always take part in Julia so do not worry about all those Python libraries.